When I run code in Flutter, I get this error. How can I fix it?
Error: The pod "Firebase/Messaging" required by the plugin "firebase_messaging" requires a higher minimum iOS deployment version than the plugin's reported minimum version.
To build, remove the plugin "firebase_messaging", or contact the plugin's developers for assistance.
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
I try flutter pub get and the errors in the code fix it

Include version of firebase_messaging and flutter sdk also add Podfile file code (ios/Podfile) in question

Check this: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios   - if you changed Deployment Target in your Xcode project, open ios/Flutter/AppframeworkInfo.plist in your Flutter app and update the MinimumOSVersion value to match. What I think is happening - you are declaring that your app can run at minimum version of let's say iOs10 - but your plugin requires iOs12. So you need to update your minimum version to iOs12 - so it matches the plugin requirement.

This error is new, Appeared after upgrading firebase messaging to 15.0.4


Check if you have the package in dependencies on file pubspec.yaml "firebase_messaging", if you don't have run this command flutter pub add firebase_messaging

Try calling rm -rf Podfile.lock && pod install --repo-update

Then flutter pub get


if not fix the issue

Try flutter clean

Then flutter pub get


